# Meaning of $\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf p, h)$ in PBF

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, computational-physics, differentiation

I'm reading [this paper](http://mmacklin.com/pbf_sig_preprint.pdf) on Position Based Fluids and I couldn't understand the meaning of $\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf{ p_i - p_j}, h)$ in the equation 7 (see below).

> …the gradient of the
>   constraint function (1) with respect to a particle k is given by:
>   $\;\;\;\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} C_i(\mathbf p_1, \mathbf p_2, \ldots, \mathbf p_n) = \frac{1}{\rho_0} \sum\limits_j \nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf p_i - \mathbf p_j, h )$

I understand the left hand side of the equation – it is $\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} C_i = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial C_i}{\partial \mathbf{p}_{k_X}} & \frac{\partial C_i}{\partial \mathbf{p}_{k_Y}} & \frac{\partial C_i}{\partial \mathbf{p}_{k_Z}}\end{bmatrix}$. However I cannot grasp the right hand side – the function $W$ is defined (AFAIK) as $W\colon \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$, meaning that it takes an $n-$dimensional vector and a scalar as the inputs and produces a scalar.

**I don't understand what does the notation $\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k}W$ mean – in particular, why is there the subscript $\mathbf{p}_k$** – the function $W$ doesn't take $n$ vectors as input, like the $C_i$ function does, so it cannot be differentiated with respect to $\mathbf{p}_k$ (it can be only to its first – vector – parameter and its second – scalar – parameter).

---

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that $C_i\colon \mathbb R^{3n} \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is there's several $W$'s.

$$\rho_i=\sum_j W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h)=W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_1,h)+W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_2,h)+\ldots$$ dropping the mass as they do in the paper.

The thing is they're treating the particles as indistinguishable e.g. they all have equal mass, so the form of the functions/constraints applied to them are the same. So there is so $W_j$ since as a function $W_j=W_i$ except for it's arguments. It's like $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(y)$ for example, same functional form but different argument. As an example take $W(\cdot_1,\cdot_2)=W(\cdot_1 -\cdot_2)=\|\cdot_1-\cdot_2\|$
$$C_i(\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2,\mathbf{p}_3)=\sum_j W(\mathbf{p}_i,\mathbf{p}_j)=\|\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_1\|+\|\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_2\|+\|\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_3\|$$

They say that $$C_i=\frac{\rho_i}{\rho_0}-1=\frac{1}{\rho_0}\sum_j W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h) -1$$

Thus $$\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k}C_i=\frac{1}{\rho_0}\sum_j \nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h)$$

The derivatives will just be zero if there's no dependence on $\mathbf{p}_k$. You see you have several $\mathbf{p}$'s and they're treated as independent parameters, like if you had particles $1$ and $2$, their co-ordinates $\mathbf{r}_1$, $\mathbf{r}_2$, and gradients w.r.t. their positions $\nabla_1$ and $\nabla_2 $.

This is emphasised when they write 
$$\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k}C_i=\frac{1}{\rho_0}\begin{cases} \sum_j \nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h) \quad \text{ if } k=i\\ - \nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h) \quad \text{ if } k=j \end{cases}$$

The idea is if $k=i$ then every $W$ depends on $\mathbf{p}_i$, but if $k=j$ for specific $j$ then only that term in the sum is non-zero after differentiating. The minus sign is from the chain rule, as it's $\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j$.

Comment: Thank you @snulty ! I think I got it – but just to clarify: let's consider the case when $k=j$ for example: It is still a sum, but all the elements of the sum that do not contain $\mathbf{p}_k$ are "zeroed-out" because of the chain rule. In the end I can ignore the $\mathbf{p}_k$ subscript in $-\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_k} W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h)$ and compute just $-\nabla W(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{p}_j,h)$. Is that right?

Comment: @sarasvati yes that's pretty much it. I think the notation is bad, as in choosing $k=j$ and also using $j$ for the summation.